# cannot init an instance of a subclassed namedtuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

I think I have not undertood how to define a class subclassed from a namedtuple :

```
from collections import namedtuple
PD = namedtuple('PD', 'x y z')
p1 = PD(0, 'u', 1)
print p1.x #<== this works

class PDsub(PD):
   __slots__ = ()
   def __new__(cls, x, y, z):
        self = super(PDsub, cls).__new__(cls, x, y, z)
        return self

   def __init__(self, a):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = a, a, a

   def __str__(self):
        return 'Foo'

p2 = PDsub(5) #<== this does not work
```

This code raises `TypeError : __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)`.

Any ideas why?

Comment: __new__ gets called before __init__ which is expecting multiple parameters. new and init need to have exact same number of parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Both the instance constructor (`__new__`) and your instance initializer (`__init__`) need to accept the same number of arguments.

Your `__new__` needs 4 arguments, but your `__init__` method only accepts 2. Adjust one or the other to accept the same number, or use a `*args` catch-all argument in your `__init__` method.

For example, using the following `__new__` method would make things work:

```
def __new__(cls, a):
    self = super(PDsub, cls).__new__(cls, a, a, a)
    return self
```

in which case you no longer need your `__init__` initializer *at all*.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> PD = namedtuple('PD', 'x y z')
>>> class PDsub(PD):
...     __slots__ = ()
...     def __new__(cls, a):
...         self = super(PDsub, cls).__new__(cls, a, a, a)
...         return self
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'Foo'
... 
>>> p2 = PDsub(5)
>>> p2.x, p2.y, p2.z
(5, 5, 5)
>>> str(p2)
'Foo'
```

An immutable type like a tuple often uses a `__new__` constructor *instead* of a `__init__` initializer; all the built-in immutables (`frozenset`, `str`, `tuple`) do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
def __new__(cls, x, y, z):

p2 = PDsub(5)
```

Whenever you create an object for your class, `__new__` method (constructor) is called to create it.. So, here your `__new__` method requires 4 parameters, but you have only passed 2 (*Note: - parameter **`cls`** is implicit)

So, either you change your **`__new__`** to take **2 parameters**, or you can change your **`__init__`** to take **4 parameters**, and accordingly create `your instance` by passing **3 parameters** (1st one is implicit..)