# AttributeError: can't set attribute in python

Tags: python, attributes

Here is my code

```
N = namedtuple("N", ['ind', 'set', 'v'])
def solve():
    items=[]
    stack=[]
    R = set(range(0,8))
    for i in range(0,8):
        items.append(N(i,R,8))      
        stack.append(N(0,R-set(range(0,1)),i))
    while(len(stack)>0): 
        node = stack.pop()
        print node
        print items[node.ind]   
        items[node.ind].v = node.v
```

In the last line I cant set the `items[node.ind].v` value to `node.v` as I want, and am getting the error

```
"AttributeError: can't set attribute"
```

I don't know what's wrong but it must be something based on syntax as using statements like `node.v+=1` is also showing same error. I'm new to Python, so please suggest a way to make the above change possible.

Comment: thanks for the answers but in case of comparison like `items[i].v <8` how do I do it, I just tried using a temporary variable to store its value and then use this for comparison like `temp = items[i].v` then `temp<8`.

Comment: There is no need to take special measures when *accessing* a `namedtuple`'s attributes.

Comment: there is no problem with accessing but i cant reassign it  and i understand that and its same reason why i cant use it for comparison like i mentioned `items[i].v]<8` . I need to know any better alternative like the one in answer using `._replace()`

Comment: Using it in an expression does not require replacing it.

Comment: yea it worked, dunno then why I was getting an error at that statement before :C

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
items[node.ind] = items[node.ind]._replace(v=node.v)
```

(Note: Don't be discouraged to use this solution because of the leading underscore in the function _replace. Specifically for namedtuple some functions have leading underscore which is not for indicating they are meant to be "private")

Comment: Why?⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: [Because.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams more explanation is required in this answer.  (linking to the docs is not sufficient.)

Comment: There is a reason there is an underscore in _replace! This is really bad practice unless you really know what you are doing.
See @jonrsharpe for a better solution.

Comment: @kroiz: "There is a reason ..." Yes, there is, and this is it: ["To prevent conflicts with field names, the method and attribute names start with an underscore."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace)

Comment: @Dennis, What are you saying? Are you supporting my comment or reject it?

Comment: @kroiz Dennis is saying we use underscore for methods and attributes to distinguish them from field names, jonrsharpe gave a detailed answer, but my question is about getting the best way to correct the error, using a inbuilt functionality is always better.. Even jonrsharpe mentioned that part.. Frankly i would have accepted both but stack dont allow that

Comment: According to PEP-8: "_single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator."  So which is in this case? is the underscore meant to indicate internal use? or to just to prevent some name conflict?

Comment: @kroiz: The quote in my comment above comes directly from the python 3 docs, so I would guess the latter.

Comment: Ok, Now I understand. So it is just specific to nametuple that there are some functions with underscore which *are* meant to be used as "public".

Comment: TLDR; This is a valid solution. The leading underscore in the function _replace was not meant to indicate internal usage.

Comment: This discussion is so useless. Either something is or it isn't. This is harmful and a bad developer experience.

Comment: @djvg: People were confused because you linked to a bit in the docs that is *after* the part you quoted. (Unless they've moved it since.)

Answer (score 141):

For those searching this error, another thing that can trigger `AtributeError: can't set attribute` is if you try to set a decorated `@property` that has no setter method. Not the problem in the OP's question, but I'm putting it here to help any searching for the error message directly. (if you don't like it, go edit the question's title :)

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._attr = "original value"
        # This will trigger an error...
        self.attr = "new value"
    @property
    def attr(self):
        return self._attr

Test()
```

Comment: Small note: For this to work in Python 2 you need to make `Test` a "new-style" class , i.e. explicitly derive from `object`(the first line must read `class Test(object):`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062077/1753435

Comment: I'm having this issue but with a `list` property and cannot figure out how to clear the list, any ideas? @Azmisov

Comment: @Ahmad I'd need more details, you should create a new question

Comment: Hi @Azmisov it is added here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74827320/atributeerror-cant-set-attribute-for-python-list-property

Answer (score 75):

`namedtuple`s are immutable, just like standard tuples. You have two choices:

1. Use a different data structure, e.g. a class (or just a dictionary); or
2. Instead of updating the structure, replace it.

The former would look like:

```
class N(object):

    def __init__(self, ind, set, v):
        self.ind = ind
        self.set = set
        self.v = v
```

And the latter:

```
item = items[node.ind]
items[node.ind] = N(item.ind, item.set, node.v)
```

If you want the latter, [Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562687/3001761) does the same thing more neatly using baked-in functionality.

Comment: yes after 10 mins i did what you told in the latter, and now I understand why this works but what I was doing before. Thnx

Comment: namedtuples are immutable - hits it on the nail. thanks

Comment: "Use a different data structure, e.g. a class" -- possibly a [@dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)?

Answer (score 3):

This error can be triggered if you try to redefine a member variable that is already defined in the class you inherited.

```
from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule

class Seq2SeqModel(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, bart, hparams):
        super().__init__()
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.bart: BartForConditionalGeneration = bart
        self.hparams = hparams  # This triggers the error
        # Changing above line to below removes the error
        # self.hp = hparams
```

As I was new to `PyTorch` and `PyTorch Lightning`, I did not know the `LightningModule` already had a member variable named `self.hparams`. As I tried to overwrite it in my code, it caused `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Just simply renaming my variable from `self.hparams` to something else removed the error.

Not the problem in the OP's question, but I'm putting it here to help any searching for the error message directly

Comment: yes, finally the right answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this when I incorrectly mixed dataclass and NamedTuple. Posting this here to potentially save someone from tearing out their hair.

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo(typing.NamedTuple):
    bar: str
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64102244) that Azmisov provided, adding a setter would solve the problem:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._attr = "original value"
        # This will trigger an error...
        self.attr = "new value"

    @property
    def attr(self):
        return self._attr

    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, value):
        self._attr = value


Test()
```

Answer (score -2):

For anyone else Googling in to this message, I got this error due to a copy/paste error.
The def method for the setter didn't exist with the correct name.
For example:

```
def __init__(self,a):
     self.a = a

...

@property
def a(self):
    return self._a
@a.setter
def b(self, value): # Should have used a(self,value):
    self._a = value
```