# Why does pyrlp.Serializable class not allow attributes to be edited after initialisation? How can this be done?

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum

While creating a simple blockchain in Python to understand the behind-the-scenes working myself, I came accross the `pyrlp` module. Using it is great for RLP serialization of transactions and accounts, and then they are stored in tries. However, an account's balance must be mutable, as does the nonce. I find that the rlp.Serializable class does not allow for mutable attributes in `fields`. Let me present some relevant application code using this class:

`rlp.Serializable` objects are created as follows:

```
import rlp
from rlp.sedes import binary, big_endian_int, List

class Account(rlp.Serializable):
    fields = (
        ('nonce', big_endian_int),
        ('address', binary),
        ('balance', big_endian_int)
        )

account = Account(nonce=0, address='0x927492', balance=0)
```

I expect to increase the balance by one (eg when receiving a transaction) through `account.balance += 1`

However, trying to do this returns:

> AttributeError: can't set attribute

Is there a way to change this seemingly immutable attribute?

Answer (score 0):

`Account` is an immutable class, created using [NamedTuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562425/attributeerror-cant-set-attribute-in-python/22562689).

The only way to update its attributes is to create a new instance.